# Permission testing my Android service

Tags: android, permissions, automated-tests

Background:

We have an app which is essentially a system service, it provides an API to other apps in our domain. Our service has multiple levels of permissions however, and we do dynmaic permission checking in the service it self as opposed to using manifest based permissions. This allows us to provide some APIs which are permission free, while keeping the rest of our API secured by various permissions.

Now what I would like to do is write automated tests that verify that our system calls are enforcing their various permissions. My plan to do this is to call each method and expect a security exception to be thrown. The problem is that since there are various levels of permissions, I would need to have a seperate app for every permission.

So my question: Is it possible to grant and revoke permissions from my app while running with a test runner context?